# Rendering without quality loss in Kdenlive

Tags: video-quality

I've used [SimpleScreenRecorder](http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/) for screencasting. The settings are shown below. This file is of very good quality. I've then added this clip to the Kdenlive project with the same settings as the video. To test the output, I rendered some 5 to 10 seconds of the video and the final result was not good as the source file. The bitrate and other settings during rendering are shown below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have the same use case. I want to render some audio + video as an intermediate clip for further editing. For this intermediate clip, I don't really need any compression. And I just found out that one can use a kdenlive project as a clip in another project! This avoids any rendering until one is really finished.

Answer (score 2):

To the command that kdenlive generates "acodec=aac ar..." add `preset=slow`. I'm not sure if kdenlive honors that but these presets are available for x264 in ffmpeg and avconf. They are good presets and are the same that you could choose from when you recorded your video (`superfast` in your case). `Slow` is generally a good option if you want to avoid visual quality loss.
If adding that line didn't work you can try to generate a script instead and add `-preset slow` after `-vcodec` but before the output file.
You probably want to delete the `vb=%bitrate%` bit, the preset will have its own value for that.

If you want to be really lossless in terms of video information you need to choose a lossless codec. I'm a bit puzzled that you have so few formats available. Maybe the "Show all profiles" checkbox gives you more options?
A recommendable codec for screen recordings would be QuickTime Animation or any other RLE based codec.
The Dirac codec from BBC is also a great lossless opensource codec, it can be found under the name `libschroedinger` in ffmpeg.

Comment: There are some lossless codecs listed: Lossless FFV1+FLAC, Lossless HuffYUV+FLAC, Lossless MPEG-2+AC3, Lossless MPEG-4+PCM and Lossless H.264+AAC. Which one amongst these would you recommend?

Comment: The lossless MPEG profiles can't be truly lossless and the h264 lossless profile is extremly bad supported by software not based on ffmpeg/x264. FFV1 is a codec by the FFMpeg devs and in an experimental state, also again bad compatability outside the linux world.
I would recommend to go with HuffYUV but try PCM instead  of FLAC if possible. Be aware that HuffYUV produces extremly huge files.
If you are doing your final encode and are not encoding the file a second time after your export I recommend to make a good quality h264 encode instead.